# Log on failed. Crystal Report 13 for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am facing a problem with Crystal Report, in the deployment Server (i.e Windows 2003 Server), my example was working in Crystal Report 10..for visual Studio 2008, but when I upgraded to the new Crystal Report 13 for Visual Studio 2010, it gives me the following error:
Error
Database logon failed.

I have used to use Typed DataSet for the ReportDocument, and from CodeBehind I set reportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable), and it was working fine in the previews version, but in the new version it gives me the previews error.

By the way the report working fine my local pc where Visual Studio 2010 installed..

Kind Regards
Bassam Basamad

Comment: My problem was solved.
But the problem strange for me, because I have just changed in Application Pool of IIS -> in Identity tab , i changed from Local System to Network Service User,
By the way Local System has more privilege than Network Services, but It works fine when I put Network Services, and also I was putting Identity in web.config to user which is Administrator on the system I also remove this user from the web.config then It works fine. But this settings was running on the old version of the crystal report for the users (Local System and My Administrator User).
any comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone will face this problem in future.

The problem because if you run two version in the Same Application Pool, it will not work, it will give log failed, but if you create another Application pool, for the Crystal Report 13 for visual studio 2010 it will work fine.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

First goto the `app.config` file and update the code below
add like this:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Add the line `useLegacyRuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` into startup tag.